# Is the simplicial objects functor a comonad?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory

Let $T$ be the functor of simplical objects $[\Delta^{\mathrm {op}},-]:\mathrm{Cat} \to \mathrm{Cat}$. I am trying to construct counit and comultiplication maps $\eta$ and $\mu$ to make $(T,\eta,\mu)$ a comonad.

For the counit, the component at some category $c$, is $\eta_c:[\Delta^{\mathrm{op}},c] \to c$. Which I need to choose such that it is right adjoint to my comultiplcation map, with components $\mu_c:[\Delta^\mathrm{op}, c] \to [\Delta^\mathrm{op},[\Delta^\mathrm{op},c]]$. Which should be easy to specify as a diagonal map (simplicial into bisimplical). Now I need to get a right adjoint of this to get $\eta$ however I am struggling to come up with one.

My overall goal is to write down the canonical resolution of the "comonad" $T$ which would give me a simplicial object in cat representing bi-, tri-, simplicial objects at each level. Which can equivalently be thought of as an internal category of $\mathrm{sSet}$.

I have tried to figure out constructing a (co)free cobar from an endofunctor but I have had no luck working that out.

How would I make this construction work?

Comment: I don't understand the comultiplication. I'm used to thinking of the "diagonal" as a way to get from bisimplicial objects to simplicial objects -- this functor is induced by the diagonal $\Delta^{op} \to \Delta^{op} \times \Delta^{op}$. Reflecting on this, I see a monad structure on $T$, where the unit is given by taking the constant simplicial object. But I don't see a comonad structure. If you use the augmented simplex category, there is the "decalage" comonad structure on $[\Delta_a^{op},-]$ induced by the join operation (with counit induced by $\{[-1]\} \to \Delta_a^{op}$).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\eta_c$ being right adjoint to $\mu_c$? I mean, in what sense could $F:X\to Y$ be right adjoint to $G:X\to Z$? A right adjoint to $G:X\to Z$ must be a functor from $Z$ to $X$, not from $X$ to $Y$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The components don't have adjoints, the functors in $2-\mathrm{Cat}$ do.

Comment: @SimplySet Sorry what you say is even more cryptic. Could you *name* these functors? Which functor is adjoint to which?? A transformation $[\Delta^{\mathrm{op}},-]\to\operatorname{identity}$ cannot be adjoint to a transformation $[\Delta^{\mathrm{op}},-]\to[\Delta^{\mathrm{op}},[\Delta^{\mathrm{op}},-]]$, what else do you have in mind?

Comment: Also, could you remove the algebraic geometry tag and add the tag simplicial stuff instead? I believe it would be more appropriate this way.

Comment: It is still unclear what do you mean by adjoint but in any case by 2-Yoneda every natural $\eta$ is given by evaluation at some $n$; more precisely,$$\eta_c(X)=X_{\eta_{\Delta^\mathrm{op}}(\mathrm{identity})}$$